# IntegrityError: App_userprofile.user_id may not be NULL

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm working on the page, where user can edit some of his/her attributes like telephone.

The problem is that those attributes can be stored either in built-in User module or in it's `UserProfile` (`user = OneToOneField(User)`).

So I've created custom forms for updating. If user goes to `xxx/edit-profile`, those forms are filled by `user` and `user.userprofile` instances. The problem is, since I've not included all fields into this forms, that during `form.save()`, error is being raised:

```
IntegrityError: App_userprofile.user_id may not be NULL
```

To be clear, I attach Forms, Models and View:

Forms:

```
class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('last_name','first_name',)

class UserProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('telephone',)
```

View:

```
@login_required
def edit_user(request):
    user = request.user
    user_profile = user.userprofile

    if request.method=='POST':
        user_profile_update_form = UserProfileUpdateForm(request.POST)
        user_update_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST)
        if user_profile_update_form.is_valid() and user_update_form.is_valid():

            user_update_form.save()
            user_profile_update_form.save()

            return render(request,'auth/profiles/my-profile.html')
        else:
            print user_profile_update_form.errors
            print user_update_form.errors
    else:

        user_profile_update_form = UserProfileUpdateForm(instance=user_profile)
        user_update_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=user)
        return render(request,'auth/profiles/edit-profile.html',
                      context={'user_profile_update_form':user_profile_update_form,
                               'user_update_form':user_update_form})
```

MODEL:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='userprofile')

    # ATRIBUTY KTORE BUDE MAT KAZDY
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=40,null=True)

    HOW_DO_YOU_KNOW_ABOUT_US_CHOICES = (
            ('coincidence',u'It was coincidence'),
            ('relative_or_friends','From my relatives or friends'),
            )
    how_do_you_know_about_us = models.CharField(max_length=40, choices=HOW_DO_YOU_KNOW_ABOUT_US_CHOICES, null=True)

    MARITAL_STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('single','Single'),
        ('married','Married'),
        ('separated','Separated'),
        ('divorced','Divorced'),
        ('widowed','Widowed'),
    )
    marital_status = models.CharField(max_length=40, choices=MARITAL_STATUS_CHOICES, null=True)

    # OD KIAL STE SA O NAS DOZVEDELI
    # A STAV

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.user.first_name,self.user.last_name)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.user.first_name,self.user.last_name)
```

Comment: You should probably reconsider your design. Much simpler to create a custom user subclass with ask the fields you want.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Do you mean that it would be better to do what UserProfile do, but other way? I would appreciate if you show me how do you mean that. Thanks

Comment: See the docs on [substituting a custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I suppose that this is not a regular way but it works. The point is that if I wanted to save forms, there were empty fields (for example ID).

So I pull a data (in dictionary format) from those forms and set current logged users attributes using this data. So the user keep his attributes and those, which were in form are changed.

```
        if user_profile_update_form.is_valid() and user_update_form.is_valid():

            for k, v in user_update_form.cleaned_data.iteritems():
                exec (u"user.{} = '{}'".format(k, v))
            for k, v in user_profile_update_form.cleaned_data.iteritems():
                exec (u"user.userprofile.{} = '{}'".format(k, v))
            user.save()
            user_profile.save()
```